# filtering dictionary of list's based on the value of element in the list

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

Below given is a dictionary of list's :

```
my_dict = {'mercury':[10], 'venus':[20], 'earth':[30],'mars':[40],'jupiter':[50],'saturn':[60]}
```

I would like to return a dictionary having only key:value pairs, who's value is greater than or equal to 30

This is the script I have written so far

```
for k,v in my_dict.items():

      for i in v:
        if i >= 30:
            new_dict = {k:v} 
print(new_dict)
```

But the issue is new_dict has only last key:value pair. Instead, I would like to have all key:value pairs which satisfy the condition.

Comment: `new_dict = {k:v}` Why would you expect `new_dict` to contain anything **other** than the last pair? It is potentially getting overwritten every iteration

Answer (score 0):

With your syntax :

```py
new_dict = {}
for k,v in my_dict.items():

      for i in v:
        if i >= 30:
            new_dict.update({k:v})
print(new_dict)  # {'earth': [30], 'mars': [40], 'jupiter': [50], 'saturn': [60]}
```

One line solution:

```py
new_dict = {k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if v[0] >= 30}
print(new_dict)  # {'earth': [30], 'mars': [40], 'jupiter': [50], 'saturn': [60]}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! now i understand where i missed